# To prove $\overline{ f(\bar{z})}$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f(z)$ analytic. Prove that $\overline{ f(\bar{z})}$ is also analytic.

How do I use the concept of analytic of $f(z)$ here? any help

Answer (score 1):

Use the series expansion of $f$ around a point. If you conjugate $z$ first and then $f$, the coefficients are conjugated and you still have a series expansion around each point.

Comment: how to put bar on $f(\bar{z})$??  by which command ?

Comment: @Eklavya `\overline{f(z)}` gives $\overline{f(z)}$. The `\overline{}` command adapts to the length of the argument, so for example you can get $\overline{z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4}$ using `\overline{z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4}`.