# Does $f(\bar{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$ generally?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been playing around with this and noticed that it worked for a few functions.  Does it work generally?  And does that mean that if $f(z)$ is entire or analytic, it's conjugate won't be since $f(\bar{z})$ isn't analytic?

Comment: This doesn't hold generally, consider $f(z)=i$ identically. It is true however if $f(x)\in\Bbb R$ for $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Wojowu ... and holomorphic (consider $f(z) = \operatorname{Im}(z)$.)

Comment: @kennytm Yes, sure enough.

Comment: @wojowu, what if I specify that $f(z)$ is not a constant function?

Comment: $f(z)=iz{}{}{}$

Comment: ...see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102885/how-do-i-rigorously-show-fz-is-analytic-if-and-only-if-overlinef-barz , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644483/analyticity-of-overline-f-bar-z-given-fz-is-analytic?rq=1 , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551458/complex-conjugates-of-holomorphic-functions and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617232/to-prove-overline-f-barz-is-analytic?rq=1

Comment: So from what I read in the other threads, if $f(z)$ is analytic, $f(\overline{z})$ and $\overline{f(z)}$ are analytic only when $f(z)$ is constant but $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is analytic in general?